# add another background image to change background during playing game

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

```
func createBackgrounds() {
    for i in 0...2 {
       let bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "BG Day")
       bg.name = "BG"
       bg.zPosition = 0;
       bg.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
       bg.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(i) * bg.size.width, y: 0)
       self.addChild(bg)
    }
}
```

If I want to add another background image after 2 minutes to `BG Night`, how can I write coding in swift 2?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SKAction.runBlock` to run some code in the future

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    var background: SKSpriteNode?

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        super.didMoveToView(view)
        changeBackgroundIn2Mintues()
        self.background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "OLD_BG_IMAGE_NAME")
    }

    private func changeBackgroundIn2Mintues() {

        let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(60 * 2)
        let changeBG = SKAction.runBlock { [unowned self] in
            self.background?.removeFromParent()
            self.background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "NEW_BG_IMAGE_NAME")
        }
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait, changeBG])
        self.runAction(sequence)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by animating a `UIImage`. As follows:

```
let bgImageArray = [UIImage(named: "BG Day")!, UIImage(named: "BG Night")!]

bg.animationImages = bgImageArray
bg.animationDuration = 120 //seconds
bg.animationRepeatCount = 0 //forever
bg.startAnimating()
```

Then just put the image `bg` at the back of your view.

Comment: bg.animationImages = bgImageArray
bg.animationDuration = 120 //seconds
bg.animationRepeatCount = 0 //forever
bg.startAnimating() // Everything shows error..

Comment: You need to have a UIImage called **bg** for it to work, not a SKSpriteNode.