# How can I use multiple background image in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

```
func createBackgrounds() {
    for i in 0...2 {
       let bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background 1")
       bg.name = "BG"
       bg.zPosition = 0;
       bg.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
       bg.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(i) * bg.size.width, y: 0)
       self.addChild(bg)
    }
 }
```

I am trying to put two background images for looping forever, just like after few minutes if i want to make change background 1 to 2,then How can I write a code for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add another background image to change background during playing game](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38448908/add-another-background-image-to-change-background-during-playing-game)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better use NSTimer to in objective C you use NSTimer like this:

`NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10.00, target: self, selector: #selector(self.randomShowedImage), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)`

then set the transition to make it more smooth using CATransition, I ever set the transition like this:

> `let transition: CATransition = CATransition()
>           transition.duration = 3.0
>           transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
>           transition.type = kCATransitionFade
>           self.bgImageView.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: nil)`

correct me if I'm wrong. I updated the answer in swift

Comment: I updated the answer in Swift 2. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you.